# What selector to use on a disabled checkbox to change the pseudo-element of the corresponding label?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've made a checkbox, made it invisible via `clip: rect(0 0 0 0)` and styled the label of that checkbox.
I used the

`input[type="checkbox"] + label:before` selector

to style a custom checkbox and the

`input[type="checkbox"] + label:after` selector

to style a custom "checked" sign.

I have multiple checkboxes on a page which dynamically change themselves to be disabled, but not hidden (as i want the user to see the options available).

However, if i disable the checkbox via `disabled="disabled"` it is still clickable. I changed the color of the `label` and the color of the `label:before`element successfully.

**BUT:**

If I click on the disabled checkbox (or the label, to be more accurate), as long as I hold the mousekey down, a different color (in my case: black) shows up - but just for the `label:before`-element.

Here is the code a little more densed:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
    input[type="checkbox"] + label
    {
        position: relative;
        top:-1px;
        padding: 0px;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none;
    }
        input[type="checkbox"] + label:before
        {
            content: '';
            color: #F00;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            margin-top: -9px;
            border: 2px solid #006c39;
            border-radius:4px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        input[type="checkbox"] + label:after
        {
            content: '';
            background-color: #900;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 4px;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
              -ms-transform: scale(0);
                  transform: scale(0);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
              -ms-transform-origin: 50%;
                  transform-origin: 50%;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
                  transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
        }

        input[type="checkbox"] + label:after
        {
            background-color: transparent;
            top: 50%;
            left: 4px;
            width: 8px;
            height: 3px;
            margin-top: -4px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: rgb(75,177,49);
            border-width: 0 0 3px 3px;
            -webkit-border-image: none;
               -o-border-image: none;
                  border-image: none;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
              -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
                  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0);
            -webkit-transition: none;
                  transition: none;
        }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after
    {
        content: '';
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
              transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
              transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
    }
```

code based on an article on maddesigns.de (in german):

http://maddesigns.de/individuelle-checkbox-radio-inputs-1396.html

the code for the disabled checkboxes:

```
input[type="checkbox"].inactive + label,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:focus + label,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:hover + label,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:active + label
        {
            color:#999;
            border-color:#999;
        }
input[type="checkbox"].inactive + label::before,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:focus + label::before,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:hover + label::before,
input[type="checkbox"].inactive:active + label::before
            {
                border-color:#999;
                color:#999;
            }
```

I've added the `.inactive`class to all disabled checkboxes, so i don't have to select via
`input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:active + label::before`
and the likes of it.

So, any suggestions, **HOW** one could change the color of the `label:before` of a disabled checkbox on mousedown?

**EDIT:**

The Effect shows up in FireFox, Chrome, Opera and Android Webkit.

The Effect does **not** show up in IE11, Safari (IOS) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o02rfy02/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"However, if i disable the checkbox via disabled="disabled" it is still clickable"_ which browser? With disabled atribute I can't click the checkbox and this is just as it should be

Comment: added the tested browser. By clickable i mean you can click on it with nothing happening. The status is not changed (it doesn't get checked). But the colorchange applies. And that's bothering me.

Comment: sorry but I can't see any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a different css-file (which still applies) I found the following styling:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:active + label:before
{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0;
          transition-duration: 0;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.2);
          filter: brightness(0.2);
}
```

I could change the color all day long with no effect if the filter drains all color out of it.

Now it's working properly - as it should.

Comment: This is why in fiddle I could not see the change :)